# catkin_make reports 'invoking "make" fails'

Tags: moveit, catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Today I tried to install moveit from source, so far I only used the debians. I am using Ros Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04

When executing catkin_make I got the following error at 73% of the build process:
linking CXX executable /home/wouter/ros/workspace/moveit/devel/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group
[ 73%] Built target move_group
Linking CXX shared library /home/wouter/ros/workspace/moveit/devel/lib/libmoveit_move_group_default_capabilities.so
[ 73%] Built target moveit_move_group_default_capabilities
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed

Do you have any idea why invoking "make" fails?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61132/catkin_make-reports-%27invoking-%22make%22-fails%27/) by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error was that some headers of the debian-installed moveit pacakages were selected, whereas the source-installed headers should have been selected. After deleting the debians everything worked fine. Thanks Isucan for your assistance!

---

Originally posted by [Wouter](https://answers.ros.org/users/879/wouter/) with karma: 130 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rosrookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/3050/rosrookie/) on 2013-04-24**:
Hello I'm in the same situation. Can you or someone else tell me where I can find the debian headers I have to delete? Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [Robin C](https://answers.ros.org/users/2477/robin-c/) on 2013-05-05**:
Hi, I've just dealt with the same problem and I can't find neither these debians headers. Could we have more precision please?

**Comment by [JamesAngsy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21979/jamesangsy/) on 2015-04-08**:
Hi, where to delete the debian headers?